# Is there any way to print a specific letter of string without indexing?

Tags: python

Write a Python program that reads a line from the user and prints the first character of the given
input.

| Sample Input | Sample Output |
| --- | --- |
| The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog | T |
| Python is an interpreted language | P |

```py
N=('Python is an interpreted language ')
Print(N[0])
```

Comment: What are you asking? You seem to have the answer in the question. Did you mean to post a question with its answer, or are you not getting the right output? *What is your question?*

Comment: @Tomerikoo  I think the question was "without indexing", while the answer in the question uses indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could

```py
print(next(iter(N)))
```

It creates an iterator from string N. And `next(it)` gives the next element in the iteration, which, the first time, is the first element.